# Why is self.navigationController nil in a storyboard application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an iOS storyboard-based application which uses the `navigationController` to control the view transitions. The app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPrincipal"  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

In the initial view, pushed by the initial navigation controller, I push the next view like:

```
 [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPrincipal" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerUsuario"];
 self.ViewUsuarioVIP = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerUsuario"];          
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.ViewUsuarioVIP animated:YES];
```

Although the next view is successfully pushed, `self.navigationController` is `nil` and the navigation bar does not appear.

```
//
//  ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageControl.h"
#import "ViewUsuario.h"
#import "SaibaMaisViewController.h"
#import "WebService.h"
#import "ViewCaptainViewController.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, PageControlDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *_scrollView;
    IBOutlet PageControl *_pageControl;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *leftArrow;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *rightArrow;

    }
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *_scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *_imageScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PageControl *_pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *leftArrow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *rightArrow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewUsuario *ViewUsuarioVIP;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewCaptainViewController *ViewCaptainVIP;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SaibaMaisViewController *SaibaMaisViewControllerVIP;
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebService *WebServiceVIP;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *photo;


@end
```

I tried to post a image with the storyboard but I am not allowed to do so. But, the Navigation Controller is the RootView. The ViewUsaruio declaration is:

```
//
//  ViewUsuario.h
//  FlyVIP
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NovoVoo.h"
#import "VoosExistentesTableViewController.h"
#import "VooAbertosViewController.h"

@interface ViewUsuario : UIViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NovoVoo *NovoVooVIP;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VoosExistentesTableViewController *VoosExistentesVIP;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VooAbertosViewController *VoosAbertosVIP;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *photo;


@end
```

Comment: In what method does that code appear?  Edit your question to include the entire method, including the method declaration.

Comment: I guess you had not embed the navigationController correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Many times, your app acting strange in the iOS simulator is just XCode being weird.

Quit XCode entirely, then run your app again.

If this persists, you have a problem with how you've set the storyboard up. Most likely your view controller is not embedded within a navigation controller in the storyboard.

I like [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) as it has easy to follow examples and many screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to explain the structure of your storyboard, and the header of your ViewControllerUsuario view controller. Where have you defined a navigation controller in your storyboard?

If you want to have a navigation controller as the root view controller for your storyboard, you have to define one in the storyboard. One is not created for free. Note that if you create a storyboard with any other view controller as the root then you can select "embed in" from the editor menu. That will change the root view controller to a navigation controller and make the previous view controller the first child of the navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks Duncan Shouldn't nvagationController property be automatically visible and initialized by the initialization procedure when I define a storyboard's navigation controller and be code the initalrootview?

Comment: No. Only if you make the view controller in question a child of the navigation controller.

Comment: I removed all  navigationController definition from the project and now navigationcontroller is not nil anymore. However the navigation bars does not appear and the last view pushed at navigationController stack is shown but the controls, for example pickerView, from the previous view is still active. No control in the current view works.

Comment: You need to upload a screen shot of your storyboard to a third party image site and post it here. Tell use which view controller scenes have which IDs. Its pretty much impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing it. Also go back to your original post and post the entire method that instantiates the view controller from the storyboard, and

Comment: Thanks Duncan but I cannot post the entire project without exposing the company's business. Anyway, you helped a lot.

Comment: you forgot to mark the answer. self.navigationcontroller will return the nereast navigation controller if any. if your view stack does not have a navigation controller, it will be nil.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem... You can simply refer to it using getter method, i.e.:

```
[self navigationController]
```

Comment: This is the same as self.navigationContoller